# Represent regular expression as context free grammar

Tags: regex, parsing, syntax, language-agnostic, ocaml

I am hand-writing a parser for a simple regular expression engine.

The engine supports `a .. z` `|` `*` and concatenation and parentheses

Here is the CFG I made:

```
 exp = concat factor1
 factor1 = "|" exp | e
 concat = term factor2
 factor2 = concat | e
 term = element factor3
 factor3 = * | e
 element = (exp) | a .. z
```

which is equal to

```
 S = T X
 X = "|" S | E
 T = F Y 
 Y = T | E
 F = U Z
 Z = *| E
 U = (S) | a .. z
```

For alternation and closure, I can easily handle them by looking ahead and choose a production based on the token. However, there is no way to handle concatenation by looking ahead cause it is implicit.

**I am wondering how can I handle concatenation or is there anything wrong with my grammar?**

And this is my OCaml code for parsing:

```
type regex = 
  | Closure of regex
  | Char of char
  | Concatenation of regex * regex
  | Alternation of regex * regex
  (*| Epsilon*)


exception IllegalExpression of string

type token = 
  | End
  | Alphabet of char
  | Star
  | LParen
  | RParen
  | Pipe

let rec parse_S (l : token list) : (regex * token list) = 
  let (a1, l1) = parse_T l in
  let (t, rest) = lookahead l1 in 
  match t with
  | Pipe ->                                   
      let (a2, l2) = parse_S rest in
      (Alternation (a1, a2), l2)
  | _ -> (a1, l1)                             

and parse_T (l : token list) : (regex * token list) = 
  let (a1, l1) = parse_F l in
  let (t, rest) = lookahead l1 in 
  match t with
  | Alphabet c -> (Concatenation (a1, Char c), rest)
  | LParen -> 
     (let (a, l1) = parse_S rest in
      let (t1, l2) = lookahead l1 in
      match t1 with
      | RParen -> (Concatenation (a1, a), l2)
      | _ -> raise (IllegalExpression "Unbalanced parentheses"))
  | _ -> 
      let (a2, rest) = parse_T l1 in
      (Concatenation (a1, a2), rest)


and parse_F (l : token list) : (regex * token list) = 
  let (a1, l1) = parse_U l in 
  let (t, rest) = lookahead l1 in 
  match t with
  | Star -> (Closure a1, rest)
  | _ -> (a1, l1)

and parse_U (l : token list) : (regex * token list) = 
  let (t, rest) = lookahead l in
  match t with
  | Alphabet c -> (Char c, rest)
  | LParen -> 
     (let (a, l1) = parse_S rest in
      let (t1, l2) = lookahead l1 in
      match t1 with
      | RParen -> (a, l2)
      | _ -> raise (IllegalExpression "Unbalanced parentheses"))
  | _ -> raise (IllegalExpression "Unknown token")
```

Comment: You just need to construct FIRST sets, as with any other LL grammar. So FIRST(factor2) = FIRST(concat) = FIRST(term) = FIRST(element) = {`(`, `a`, ..., `z`}

Comment: I will say here that I really don't get the point of LL(1) parsers. There are perfectly good LALR(1) generator tools, including ones written for and in ocaml, and LR parsing does not require that you change your grammar to associate incorrectly and be unreadable. Yes, it's an opinion.

Comment: @rici Hi, thanks for your reply. Do you mind to elaborate a bit more? I change my parse_T function, which now use LParen and char as lookahead token. But when I test "a(b|c)*",  "*" doesnt not get recognized by my parser

Comment: That will be a problem with your function to parse factor3, I suppose. It's been more than a decade since I've touched ocaml, I'm afraid, which (combined with my bias as expressed in my second comment) is why I haven't tried to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

For a LL grammar the FIRST sets are the tokens that are allowed as first token for a rule. To can construct them iteratively till you reach a fixed point.

1. a rule starting with a token has that token in its FIRST set
2. a rule starting with a term has the FIRST set of that term in its FIRST set
3. a rule T = A | B has the union of FIRST(A) and FIRST(B) as FIRST set

Start with step 1 and then repeat steps 2 and 3 until the FIRST sets reach a fixed point (don't change). Now you have the true FIRST sets for your grammar and can decide every rule using the lookahead.

Note: In your code the parse_T function doesn't match the FIRST(T) set. If you look at for example 'a|b' then is enters parse_T and the 'a' is matched by the parse_F call. The lookahead then is '|' which matches epsilon in your grammar but not in your code.